# How to add a certain amount of elements in a vector without using a loop C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm trying to add 100 elements in a vector located inside a class, but I can't use a for loop because the vector is defined outside of a function. Is there any way for me to add the values without having to manually list them?

```
class Player
{
    vector<bool> able; // set 10 values to 0
    vector<bool> tertiary; // set 100 values to 0
    
    void other_funcs()
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: *" I can't use a for loop because the vector is defined outside of a function"* - That doesn't stop you using a for loop.

Comment: If you can add items to the vector without a loop then you can add them with a loop. Perhaps you can elaborate on `//stuff`?

Comment: You can't use a for loop in a class, it has to be done inside a function. Doing so raises the error: expected unqualified-id before 'for'.

Comment: Show us the code with the error. You have a different problem. It sounds like you're trying to put code outside a function which will not work but has nothing to do with it being a class or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of `bool` should really be `true`or `false` although `0` will convert to `false`.

If you want to set your members as indicated in your code you can do that this way:

```
class Player
{
    std::vector<bool> able = std::vector<bool>(10, false);
    std::vector<bool> tertiary = std::vector<bool>(100, false);

    void other_funcs()
    {
    }
};
```

The statement `std::vector<bool>(10, false)` constructs a *vector* with `10` elements all set to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::fill`:

```
std::fill(able.begin(), able.begin() + 10, 0);
```

Make sure your vector has enough space to do so:

```
std::vector<bool> able(10);
```

Comment: Why not just use the `vector<T>(size, value)`?